# HTML Snippets not working in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext-snippet

I created the following snippet in Sublime Text. It seems doesn't get triggered by the tab. If I change the contents to some other language, or some plain text, it is working. For html, it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

```
   <snippet>
        <content><![CDATA[
    <li class="timeline-inverted">
      <div class="timeline-badge ${1:type)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
      <div class="timeline-panel wow fadeInDown">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
          <h4 class="timeline-title">${2:year}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-body">
          <p>${3:data}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    ]]></content>
        <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>tmeln</tabTrigger>
    <description>timeline-body</description>
    </snippet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because on line 4 in the class attribute of the `<div>` you open with a curly brace `{` but close with parentheses `)`.

To resolve the issue use this snippet (removed the parentheses and added a curly brace)

**The snippet**

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
    <li class="timeline-inverted"><!--   ▾ Here -->
      <div class="timeline-badge ${1:type)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
      <div class="timeline-panel wow fadeInDown">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
          <h4 class="timeline-title">${2:year}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-body">
          <p>${3:data}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    ]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>tmeln</tabTrigger>
    <description>timeline-body</description>
</snippet>
```

Hope this helps!